# If variable contents ends with <br> delete it

Tags: php, regex

```
    $var1 = "a<b>
        b<br>
        c
";

        $var2 = "a<b>
        b<br>
        c<br>
";
```

How can I detect and delete the `<br>` after the c in `$var2`?

Thanks.

Comment: What about the empty element equivalent `<br/>`?

Comment: @andyb PHP nl2br function is generating <br> not <br />

Comment: @oaziz, I'm not sure which PHP version you're using, but PHP 5.2.17 and 5.3.5 are generating `<br />`. I can't even recall seeing `<br>` after using `nl2br()` in last few years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a regex solution

```
preg_replace('#<br>\\s*$#', '', $var2);
```

it is also working with optional newlines and whitespace at the end of the string.

`$` anchors the regex to the end of the string.

`\s` is a whitespace character (this includes newlines)

`*` means 0 or more

That means the regex matches a `<br>` followed by optional whitespace at the end of the string and `preg_replace` replaces it with an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

```
$var2 = "a<b>b<br>c<br>";

$var2 = trim($var2);
if(substr($var2, -4) == "<br>")
{
    $var2 = substr($var2, 0, -4); 
}

echo($var2); //a<b>b<br>c
```

Comment: This is probably faster than a regular expression. +1 for simple solution.

Comment: I'd put this in a while loop, like `while((substr($var2, -4) == "<br>"))` as I'd guess this will be oaziz next question (e.g. *how to remove multiple <br>*). ;)

Comment: @develroot This doesn't work with my modified example. There's a newline after the last <br>

Comment: well..try it now. i've added `trim()`

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `preg_replace()` to remove all newlines and `br` tags (`<br>`, `<br/>`, `<br />` etc):

```
$str = "
    a<b>
    b<br>
    c<br><br>
    <br/><br />
    <br>
";
$str = preg_replace('#(?:\s+|<br\s*/?>)+$#', '', $str);
var_dump($str);
```

Output:

```
string(28) "
    a<b>
    b<br>
    c"
```